# convert ciimage to writable format

Tags: objective-c, image, quartz-graphics, core-image

I need to convert `CIImage` to a format which could be written to disk.

Currently I am using the following code to convert it to JPG format .

```
 NSBitmapImageRep* rep = [[[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithCIImage:result] autorelease];

 NSData *JPEGData = [rep representationUsingType:NSJPEGFileType properties:nil];
[JPEGData writeToFile:targetPath atomically:YES];
```

But the real memory usage shoots up to above 100 MB . My application requires me to handle  a large number of images so i need to optimise my memory usage.

Can anyone please suggest anything ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's the cumulative memory that's an issue, and not just one image, you can try wrapping the two last lines in your own autorelease pool:

```
@autoreleasepool {
    NSData *JPEGData = [rep representationUsingType:NSJPEGFileType properties:nil];
    [JPEGData writeToFile:targetPath atomically:YES];
}
```

Comment: I have already kept these statements inside an autorelease pool .. but the problem persists

Comment: I admit that I'm not sure, then.